# Use Rspec to test that a method does not hit the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm writing Rspec tests for caching in my Rails 3 app.  I use Redis as the cache store.

I have a method that will attempt to pull data from Redis and if not found, will use the database.

Is there a way to test that the database is not accessed?  (So I am assured the data is pulled from Redis.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [activerecord](/questions/tagged/activerecord) and [rspec-mocks](/questions/tagged/rspec-mocks) you could mock the model calls to raise errors. Here's an example:

```
describe 'when cached' do
  it 'should not hit the database' do
    # first request should add the object to the cache
    get '/users/1'

    # make db calls fail
    expect(User).not_to receive(:find)

    # send the request again
    get '/users/1'
  end
end
```

Comment: `get '/users/1'; User.should_not_receive(:find); get '/users/1'`

Comment: This is now deprecated

Comment: @AntoineLizée yup! old answer. I just updated it to the new syntax. Thanks!